# Hide a samba share from a custom usergroup

Tags: include, samba

In Linux, I have 2 usergroups A and B with a bunch of users in them, for both of them I have configured a few samba shares.
Group A has access to a share, B to another one.

Now I want to hide shares that groups don't have access to, from those users.

In smb.conf, by using browseable = no , and include = /etc/samba/custom/%U.conf, you can hide certain shares that users don't have access to.
For user groups however (no primary group), I can't seem to get it fixed. 
Include = /etc/samba/custom/%G.conf only works for a primary usergroup.

Is there another solution besides changing primary usergroup each time I create a linux/samba user ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this detailed answer by a friend of mine `http://askubuntu.com/a/531476/330840`

The key here is that you need to set permission for user groups so they are allowed or not allowed to enter a folder.

Comment: Thx, already made a workaround by making a shellscript to change primary usergroup of an user, after I create one. Was ok for mr. Bagnoli ;)